# Getting the hashmap values of an object list using lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Lets assume I have an object:

```
class MyObject {
    private int id;
    private HashMap<Integer, OtherObject> otherObjects;
}
```

What I want to do is access the `otherObjects` property of a list of `MyObject` and add them all to a `otherObjects` `list`.

I could use a `.forEach` and `.addAll` into the `otherObjects` `list` but I'm trying see if it is possible to use lambdas to achieve this. I thought of something like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
myObjectList.stream()
    .map(o -> o.getOtherObjects())
    .map(oo -> oo.values())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But there seems to be a conflict with the object types. I'm guessing it is because I start with a stream of objects and end up with a stream of lists and it gets confused. How can I achieve this? And more generally, how can I gather a list of objects of many parent objects into a single list?

Comment: Can you provide a short but complete example of the problem, including the error you're currently seeing? (I suspect you just want `flatMap`...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `flatMap` method instead of the last `map` call. The `flatmap` method concatenates the streams that the given function returns, into one stream. Like this:

```
myObjectList.stream()
    .map(o -> o.getOtherObjects())
    .flatMap(oo -> oo.values().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I put this as the answer because it gave a rudimentary explanation of what `flatMap` does. Of course all answers are correct and using method references is also my style of choice.

Answer (score 5):

Use flatMap to fix the signature mismatch. Also prefer method references and win points with Haskell programmers :)

```
myObjectList.stream()
            .map(MyObject::getOtherObjects)
            .map(Map::values)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is this different in runtime environment compared to Alexander Tokarev's answer ?

Comment: What do you mean, it's Java 8?

Comment: No, I meant having 3 intermediate steps in stream pipeline vs. 1 step. Will it make any processing / runtime difference?

Comment: So you meant _run time_,  not _runtime environment_. Note that the inner loop (processing list items) is the same, only getting the list might take a few nanoseconds more. So, unless you have a million MyObjects, each with just a few OtherObjects, this cannot matter.

Comment: I meant both. Is there any chance either compiler or the jvm optimize it to have single step pipeline? BTW I really do not care few microseconds difference of run time, otherwise I won't use sequential stream.

Comment: No, it won't become a single step pipeline, but it's probable that the whole pipeline gets inlined, in which case all overhead will melt away.

Answer (score 3):

You can try flatMap:

```
myObjectList.stream()
            .flatMap(o -> o.getOtherObjects().values().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```